# Array forloop noob enquiry

Tags: java

I'm currently undertaking a project with the aim to improve my understanding of Java. Part of my project is to use an array and be able to move positions down 1 in order to slot in another element at a specific position. For example, names in alphabetical order... If I want to place an element in the middle of an array then places should be moved -1.

I've been looking around and actually found what I think could potentially be a solution on StackOverflow. Although the poster didn't actually provide full detail on what's going on. I was hoping someone could explain it to me. As I don't want to use something that I don't have a full understand off.

### This was the question :

I've had a decent search and am unable to find working code that moves down an array. What I am hoping to do, is to store the value in the last position in the array, replace the last position and then move array[20] to array[19]. This is meant to count the last 20 moves the player makes, but I'm having trouble actually storing. This is what I have attempted to do

```
//an int moveArray[20] previously stated and instantiated
int temp1, temp2;

for (int i = moveArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
{
    temp1 = moveArray[i - 1];
    temp2 = moveArray[i - 2];
    moveArray[i - 1] = moveArray[i];
    temp1 = temp2;
}
moveArray[moveArray.length - 1] = intoWalk;
```

any advice or solutions would really help, thanks

### This was the solution :

```
for(int i=0;i<moveArray.length-1;i++){ 
    moveArray[i] = moveArray[i+1];
}
moveArray[moveArray.length - 1] = intoWalk;
```

If anyone could explain the solution for me please step by step I'd extremely appreciate it

Comment: There is no better explanation than the one provided by a debugger. If you really want to learn, start up your favorite IDE, write the code and walk through it with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have the following array of strings (I'm using strings
because I think they will be easier to follow but the same principle
applies):

```
String[] moveArray = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

Say you want to remove `"A"` and shift the remaining strings to the left
by 1 so you can add "F" to the end.

```
String intoWalk = "F";
for (int i = 0; i < moveArray.length - 1; i++) {
    moveArray[i] = moveArray[i + 1];
}
moveArray[moveArray.length - 1] = intoWalk;
```

This will result in `moveArray` containing `{"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}`.

Now let's examine the setup of the loop: `for (int i = 0; i < moveArray.length - 1; i++)`

- Start the index variable `i` at `0` (the beginning).
- Keep on iterating while `i < moveArray.length - 1`. This means iterate
  over the loop from `"A"` (index `0`) through `"D"` (index `3` because `moveArray.length - 1`
  is `5 - 1` which is `4`).
- After each iteration, increment `i` by `1`.

Each iteration: `moveArray[i] = moveArray[i + 1];`

- Iteration `i == 0`:

  - `moveArray` is `{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}`.
  - Set `moveArray[0]` to `moveArray[1]`.
  - Now `moveArray` is `{"B", "B", "C", "D", "E"}`.
  - Increment `i` from `0` to `1`.
  - `i == 1` is less `4`.
- Iteration `i == 1`:

  - `moveArray` is `{"B", "B", "C", "D", "E"}`.
  - Set `moveArray[1]` to `moveArray[2]`.
  - Now `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "C", "D", "E"}`.
  - Increment `i` from `1` to `2`.
  - `i == 2` is still less `4`.
- Iteration `i == 2`:

  - `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "C", "D", "E"}`.
  - Set `moveArray[2]` to `moveArray[3]`.
  - Now `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "D", "D", "E"}`.
  - Increment `i` from `2` to `3`.
  - `i == 3` is still less `4`.
- Iteration `i == 3`:

  - `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "D", "D", "E"}`.
  - Set `moveArray[3]` to `moveArray[4]`.
  - Now `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "D", "E", "E"}`.
  - Increment `i` from `3` to `4`.
  - `i == 4` is now `4` so stop the loop.

The assignment after the loop: `moveArray[moveArray.length - 1] = intoWalk;`

- Set the last index `4` to `intoWalk` which is `"F"`.
- Now `moveArray` is `{"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}`.

That is what the solution was describing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does the same rule apply if the array is being read from a .txt file ?

Comment: @user3443834 Do you mean if you read and parsed a text file, populated an array, then you shifted all of the elements left (removing the first) and set the last element?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I mean =)

Comment: @user3443834 Then yes, it would behave exactly the same.

Comment: @user3443834 If you are going to be doing these sorts of operations frequently, [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)s are better because they provide methods such as `.removeFirst()` and `.addLast()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// for loop declaration
//    make a new int to use as a counter. start at 0 (the first index in the array)
//    run loop until the counter is not less than one less than the length of your array
//      i.e. when the test [i < moveArray.length-1] returns false.
//    increment the counter by one each iteration.
for(int i=0;i<moveArray.length-1;i++){ 
    // on each iteration set the array element at the index position of the counter
    //    to be the one that follows it.
    // this drops the first element as it gets overwritten by the second on first run.
    // this continues until the counter is at the second last index of the array
    //    at that point the last element is moved into the second last position.
    moveArray[i] = moveArray[i+1];
}
// After the loop finishes the first element has been lost and every other element has
//    moved one position towards the start of the array.
// The last and second last elements are the same right now.
// To finish off we place the new addition called 'intoWalk' at the end position.
moveArray[moveArray.length - 1] = intoWalk;
```